# Create image from string sent from iOS device

Tags: python, ios, python-3.x

I have an iOS mobile application that sends an encoded image to a Python3 server.

```
static func prepareImageAndUpload(imageView: UIImageView) -> String?
{
    if let image: UIImage? = imageView.image {
        // You create a NSData from your image
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image!, 0.5)
        // You create a base64 string
        let base64String = imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
        // And you encode it in order to delete any problem of specials char
        let encodeImg = base64String.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet()) as String!

        return encodeImg
    }

    return nil

}
```

And I am trying to receive that image using the following code:

```
imageName = "imageToSave.jpg"
fh = open(imageName, "wb")
imgDataBytes = bytes(imgData, encoding="ascii")
imgDataBytesDecoded = base64.b64decode(imgDataBytes)
fh.write(imgDataBytesDecoded)
fh.close()
```

I create the image file successfully and nothing breaks. And I can see that the filesize is correct, but the image is not correct, since it can't be opened and shows that it is broken.

I am not sure where the error can be, since the logic is as follows:

1. Encode image with base64 on iOS device
2. Send it
3. Decode image with base64 on Python3 server
4. Save image from decoded bytes

I have tried two new variants:

1. Remove `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` and
   the result was the same
2. Add urldecode in Python3 server and the result was the same

---

Comment: Why convert to string before sending to server ? You not be sure file is corrupt or valid. Send to server original image (file upload) and ignore all `EOF` bugs.(Additional: ` python -u ` (binary mode))

Comment: I tried to remove url encoding:
`let encodeImg = base64String.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet()) as String!` and it is still the same. Is that what you meant here?

Comment: Allowed charset always return a corrupted image string. Use bzip2 with jqeryajax, send pic to server. Server response a zipped(bz2) image. Encoder and decoder are not same type. Lost packet, broken connection,

Comment: I am not sure how to use jquery ajax within iOS application.

Comment: Need run on a web browser(for all os compatible ). Who can trust your aplication for runing with more permissions. Web app give more flexibility. I create an exe(for windows) always give 125ms delay. Convert scada app  to  webapp, my response is 0.87 ms now. Cross platform always a problem if not use the webapp.

Comment: I have to use an application - native app in Swift.